# Google maps (duda)

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Buen día valiosa comunidad!

Necesitaría saber cómo puedo validar una dirección en google maps y decirle que si esta fuera del rango de latitud no se valide. Esto es muy dificil de hacer? Se utiliza algun tipo de sdk distinto al mapa static ?

Muchas gracias!

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer una petición con el api de google: Geocoder y especificar la región cuando haces la consulta, si el status de la respuesta es diferente a `ok`, significa que no está dentro de la región especificada. aquí puedes encontrar información de lo que acabo de mencionar *https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?csw=1#GeocodingRequests*

Comment: Esto parece más un comentario que una respuesta, revisa [answer]